# SoapUI OAuth authentication in Soap request

Tags: soap, oauth-2.0, soapui, google-ads-api

I want to send a Soap request to google adwords endpoint ManagedCustomerService. This endpoint uses OAuth authentication and I am not able to find OAuth authentication in its authentication tab. I can only see the OAuth authentication its Rest reqests but not Soap requests

Can someone please tell me how can I use OAuth authentication in Soap requests in SOAPui

Regards
Syed

Comment: I have not used OAuth2 myself, but is there something wrong with the documentation? http://www.soapui.org/OAuth/oauth2-authorization.html

Comment: SoapUI is a client used for testing and SOAP requests and responses to Adwords or any endpoint. Usually such clients give an option for authenticating the requests but I cannot find it SOAPUI. I am not sure how to authenticate the XML SOAP requests within its body using OAuth. If it was simply username passowrd, I could provide it within the header but not sure how to authenticate the XML soap request to Adwrods using OAuth in its header

Comment: Did you try the link I posted above? Also, you should use the @<username> to start your Comment, if you would like that user to be notified.